# Ways to go from a number to 0 the fastest way

Tags: c++, algorithm

So, I have a homework like this:

Given two number `n` and `k` that can reach the `long long` limit, we do such operation:

- assign `n = n / k` if `n` is divisible by `k`
- reduce `n` by `1` if `n` is not divisible by `k`

Find the smallest number of operations to go from `n` to `0`.

This is my solution

```cpp
#define ll long long

ll smallestSteps(ll n, ll k) {
    int steps = 0;
    if (n < k) return n;
    else if (n == k) return 2;
    else {
        while (n != 0) {
            if (n % k == 0) {
                n /= k;
                steps++;
            }
            else {
                n--;
                steps++;
            }
        }
        return (ll)steps;
    }
}
```

This solution is `O(n/k)` I think?

But I think that `n` and `k` could be extremely big, and thus the program could exceed the time limit of 1s. Is there any better way to do this?

Edit 1: I use `ll` for it to be shorter

Comment: Why would you define `steps` to be `int` and then only to cast it to `ll` on return?

Comment: Aside: don't use the pre-processor if you can avoid it, use `using ll = long long;` instead.

Comment: You've called the variables `a` and `b` in your description, but `n` and `k` in the code - that's a bit confusing!

Comment: @PaulEvans Even that is a no-no in my book. Just obfuscates the code.

Comment: Continuing the stylistic comments, using names such as `ll` might seem like a good idea, but it's really not. Few other will know what it means, which leads to others having trouble understanding your code. If you want to create type-aliases, name them more "semantically", like a descriptive name that tells readers what the type is for. And if you can't come up with a good descriptive name, then just leave it and use the full standard type name.

Comment: @DeiDei You take the `long long` road, and I'll take the `ll` road... :P All kidding aside, you have a point.  That would be unacceptable in industrial grade code.

Comment: I just use `ll` in the code so that it looks shorter. I will change it back to `long long` when I send this to my teacher

Comment: @infrustration: You can make the code briefer more legitimately: e.g. `while (n)`.

Comment: Are you sure this is the complete problem? There's never a decision to make; you just need to follow a rule, and you can trivially restate the second rule as "subtracting the remainder".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a code review question, and thus belongs on [the code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Evg smallest number of operations

Comment: Hint: You don't need to subtract 1 at a time. You can subtract by more than 1 (and increase the number of steps accordingly) to ensure that the next step will be division.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The algorithm can be improved given these observations:

1. If `n<k` then `k|(n-m)` will never hold for any positive m. So the answer is `n` steps.
2. If `(k|n)` does not hold then the biggest number `m, m<n` for which it does is `n - (n%k)`. So it takes `n%k` steps until (k|m) holds again.

Actually all that you need is to keep doing division with remainder using `std::div` (or rely on compiler to optimize) and increase steps by remainder+1.

```
steps=0
while(n>0)
     mod = n%k
     n = n/k
     steps+=mod + 1
return steps
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with an even simpler main program.

Convert `n` to base `k`.  Let `d` be the number of digits in this number.
To get to 0, you will divide by `k` `(d-1)` times.
The number of times you subtract `1` is the digital sum of this number.

For instance, consider n=314, k=3.

314 in base 3 is `102122`.  This has 6 digits; the digital sum is 8.
You will have 6-1+8 steps ... 13 steps to 0.

Use your C++ packages to convert to the new base, convert the digits to integers, and do the array sum.  This pushes all the shift-count work into module methods.

Granted this won't work for weird values of `k`, but you can also steal available conversion packages instead of writing your own.

Comment: "Convert n to base k" That's already what my algorithm does, instead of printing the digits it sums them. Then it just adds number of division. Without any external C++ packages. But this is valid algorithm too.